# How transpose rows to columns in SQL query with specific content from row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have db with a structure like that - [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d6fbba16eed4fec7452bcc07b5f82edd)

[image]

As a result, I would like to get:

```
          Question1  Question2   Question3
User 1    Answer1    Answer2     Answer3
User 2    Answer1    Answer2     null
User 3    Answer1    Answer2     null
User 4    Answer1    null        null
```

And I need to have option to choose questions which will be shown. For example only 1 and 3.

```
          Question1  Question3
User 1    Answer1    Answer3
User 2    Answer1    null
User 3    Answer1    null
User 4    Answer1    null
User 5    Answer1    Answer3
```

Can you please help me to write down SQL query for this?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot instruction. 
Documentation there :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution... this leaves Dynamic SQL

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d6124b4be4843438586d0720370e532a)**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)='[question 1],[question 3]'

Select @SQL ='
select * 
 From ProcedureStepsDetails
 Pivot (max(HTMLValue) for TokenValue in ('+@SQL+') ) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

```
ProcedureId question 1  question 3
User 1      answer 1    answer 3
User 2      answer 1    
User 3      answer 1    
User 4      answer 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select ProcedureId,
    max(case when TokenValue = 'Question1' then HtmlValue end) as Question1,
    max(case when TokenValue = 'Question2' then HtmlValue end) as Question2,
    max(case when TokenValue = 'Question3' then HtmlValue end) as Question3
from table1
group by ProcedureId
```